# Add repository directory to existing branch in CVS

Tags: branch, cvs

I have the following structure in my CVS respository

```
ProjectX       
   |--> DirectoryA
   |        |--> DirectoryA1
   |        |--> DirectoryA2
   |        |--> DirectoryA3
   |--> DirectoryB
     .      .
     .      .
```

And I creted `branch1` only for `DirectoryA3`:

```
branch1:
ProjectX
   |--> DirectoryA
            |--> DirectoryA3
```

I forgot to add `DirectoryA1` and `DirectoryA2` and I want to add them to the branch to get this:

```
branch1:
ProjectX
   |--> DirectoryA
            |--> DirectoryA1
            |--> DirectoryA2
            |--> DirectoryA3
```

**What are the cvs commands needed to accomplish that?**

Answer (score 1):

Solved with the following:

```
cvs tag -r TAG-USED-WHEN-CREATING-THE-BRANCH -b branch1 ProjectX/DirectoryA/DirectoryA1
cvs tag -r TAG-USED-WHEN-CREATING-THE-BRANCH -b branch1 ProjectX/DirectoryA/DirectoryA2
```